# Can I reverse the direction of a PSC fan motor?

Tags: motor, fan

Hello I have a fan that utilizes a Kulthorn Electric KDE3F4709 fan motor.
When I google the item I originally purchased had it listed as "2-speed heavy duty thermally protected 120-Volt, 60 Hz, PSC motor".

How can I reverse the direction of this motor?

This is the motor model and diagram they provide:
[image]

Comment: Turn it around?  :)

Answer (score 2):

To reverse the motor, you would need to reverse the connection, end-to-end, of either the start winding or the run winding. The diagram seems to indicate that the windings are connected together and to the white wire somewhere inside the motor. That connection point may or may not be accessible. There is also a second run-winding connection for two-speed operation. That may indicate that the run winding can not be reversed, but it may still be possible to reverse the start winding.